# Failed to install gems via bundler Heroku, devise 4.5.0 not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to push my rails app to heroku but it keeps failing, it specifies that devise 4.5.0 is not available, yet in my other apps it has that same version of devise and i have no problems deploying to heroku.

```
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/...

       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............

       Fetching version metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..

       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..

       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.

       Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/...

       Fetching version metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..

       Your bundle is locked to devise (4.5.0), but that version could not be found in

       any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that

       means the author of devise (4.5.0) has removed it. You'll need to update your

       bundle to a different version of devise (4.5.0) that hasn't been removed in order to install.    
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.  
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: How is `devise` gem listed in your Gemfile? and do you have more than one source in it?

Comment: it's listed as gem 'devise' i have also tried to specify the version before and i kept getting the same error, and there's only one source

Comment: It's highly likely there is an issue with the bundler version you're using. Also, by the way, I just had a successful heroku deployment of a new app with `gem 'devise', '=4.2.0'`.

Comment: @imechemi this is weird, i just tried to specify gem 'devise', '=4.5.0' and it worked but now i'm getting the same error with turbolinks, i tried to specify the version for that also but i'm still getting errors, i've also tried using different version of bundlers but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by doing this

1.Remove your Gemfile.lock file using this command rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/ .bundle/ Gemfile.lock

2.Remove 'gem name' from your Gemfile.

3.Add gem back to your Gemfile.

4.bundle install.